# How can I disable google chrome's terrible sub-pixel anti-aliasing in PDFs?

Tags: linux, google-chrome, pdf, fonts, anti-aliasing

I'd just like to turn it off, because it's quite distracting when every PDF looks so colourful. I've looked through `chrome://flags` and there's an **LCD text anti-aliasing** option but it doesn't seem to affect the PDF viewer.

Here's how chrome Version 43.0.2357.125 (64-bit) on Fedora 21 renders [this PDF](http://www.hgd1952.hr/pdf_datoteke/Test_document_PDF.pdf) for me:
[image]

A little closer:

[image]

Quite different to an old version of adobe reader with only slight colouring:

[image]

And evince with no sub-pixel antialiasing:

[image]

This is what my monitor looks like up close:

[image]

From: http://www.lagom.nl/lcd-test/subpixel.php

[image]

[image]

Which looks much better than chrome's PDF viewer.

**Update:** Still an issue in Fedora 23, chrome 48.0.2564.103.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can fix your font rendering issues in the PDF viewer by installing freetype-world, since you're on Fedora (according to this bug report: https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=479400).

I'm still trying to figure out how to disable subpixel rendering in the PDF viewer on CentOS (which doesn't have a freetype-world package). So far I've tried editing ~/.fonts.conf and ~/.Xresources, and changing the Gnome system settings (based on the instructions here: https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=408079#c4).

Comment: fantastic. `sudo dnf install freetype-freeworld`. problem gone. thanks very much for taking the time to post the answer! If only it was so easy for your distro.